# Is it possible to build a custom site on a separate server using only the shopify api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node, shopify-storefront-api

I've searched everywhere for this question; and since its so hard to figure out, I'm guessing its not possible but I thought I might as well ask.

**Is it possible, using Shopify's API, to completely populate a custom website on my server and then when someone is ready to checkout send them back to shopify's checkout page?**

**So example flow;**

- my shopify site is xyz.myshopify.com
- My server has a site located on buypizza.com is a simple ecommerce site with a HTML theme. I pull product data from the API and populate the site home page
- A user clicks into a product - lets call it pizza box
- then I send a request to shopify's api to pull all the data related to pizza box and populate the product page.

**this is where I dont know how this would work**

- They hit add to cart; I can store that data in a session but how does shopify know this?
- Then I hit checkout and it takes me back to xyz.shopify.com - what am I missing. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use shopify to create order for your user

[draft  order api](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/draftorder)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is definitly possible.

You might wanna give a look at the [Shopify Storefront API (GraphQL)](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api).

About your question concerning the checkout process you have 2 options. One is to redirect the user to the default Shopify checkout (as you seem to want), and the other one is to handle the process "yourself". [See this link](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/create-a-checkout-with-storefront-api#completing-the-checkout).

If you're familiar with gatsby, you can have a look at their [official doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/building-an-ecommerce-site-with-shopify/) to see an example